# What's the difference between tex.pro and texc.pro with dvips?

Tags: dvips

I sometimes see `tex.pro` mentioned and sometimes `texc.pro` mentioned. What are the differences betweeen those two?

Possibly resulting questions:

- Are those relevant to the end user (me)?
- Should I give dvips special options to choose one over the other?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If option `-Z` is used, dvips uses `texc.pro` instead of `tex.pro`. From the manual page:

> ```
> -Z  Causes  bitmapped fonts to be compressed before they are downloaded,
>     thereby reducing the size of the PostScript font-downloading information.
>     Especially useful at high resolutions or when very large  fonts are used.
>     Will slow down printing somewhat, especially on early 68000-based Post-
>     Script printers.
> ```

Thus the `c` of `texc.pro` most likely comes from **c**ompressed.
Since usually vector fonts should be preferred over bitmapped fonts (avoiding blurred displays of the PDF file in AR), IMHO the relevance of the option is a little smaller nowadays.